# Why is file.close() terminating Python instance

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

When I run

```
file.close()
```

On my IDE it terminates the IDE. No errors, just terminates it.

When I don't use it,

```
lines[k+1][16] = count
```

I get a list index error for this list, as the file doesn't save anything and the csv becomes blank. I don't know what to do here. Any ideas?

Edit: Added more code to make reproducible.

```
df = pd.read_csv("passandpy.csv", usecols=[0], skipinitialspace=True)
df4 = pd.read_csv('passandpy.csv', usecols=[16], skipinitialspace=True)
col0 = df['Username'].tolist()
col16 = df4['Failed Attempts'].tolist()
if username_ask in col0:
    for k in range(0, len(col0)):
        lines = list()                               
        with open("passandpy.csv", "r") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                lines.append(row)
        print(lines)
        lines[16][k+1] = count
        writer = csv.writer(open('passandpy.csv', 'w'))
        writer.writerows(lines)
        csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Please post a larger portion of your code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Edited, do you also need the .csv file?

Comment: `file.close()` is not present in your example. Did you mean `csvfile.close()`?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I used file.close() as a placeholder.

Comment: Why do you do `csvfile.close()` when you have `with open("passandpy.csv", "r") as csvfile`? The with-statement will automatically close the file.

Comment: Please clarify the observed behavior. Does it terminate the execution of your script by the IDE, or does it really terminate the IDE? What IDE are you using? How are you running the script?

Comment: Note that the indexing is swapped in the question and the larger code snippet. Are you using `lines[k+1][16]` or `lines[16][k+1]`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It terminates the Python Script as a whole. Doesn't terminate the whole IDE.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I'm using lines[16][k+1]

Comment: Well, that assumes that there are at least 16 rows and at least k+1 columns. Given the variable naming above, you might want to change `lines[16][k+1]` to `lines[k+1][16]`, rerun the code and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I'm still getting "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: It is surprising that you don't get the error with `k+2`. My advice would be to create a fake copy of the dataset (at least columns 0 and 16) with a dozen rows, describe your underlying problem + expected output, and post a new question with `pandas` tag. I doubt that you can get much useful feedback here with the question as stated.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include some sample data that allows us to reproduce your problem? See [mcve] for details.